# Substitue backslash to forward slash in #include statement

Tags: c, linux, vim, command-line

I am porting my C programs from Windows to Linux. The problem is that Linux (Unix-like) does not recognize `\` as directory separator, says [here](https://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes). So I have to substitute `\` to `/` in all my `#include` statement within my project. Like this,

converting

```
#include <mydir\myhdr.h>  or
#include "mydir\myhdr.h"
```

to

```
#include <mydir/myhdr.h>  or
#include "mydir/myhdr.h"
```

How do I do this find and substitute fast? Either by command-line or Vim works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command in `vim`:

```
:g/#include/s@\\@/@g
```

You can also use `sed`:

```
$ sed -i '/#include/s@\\@/@g' code.c
```

---

If you want to substitute multiple files:

```
$ vim *.c
:argdo your_command | update
```

Or

```
$ sed -i your_command *.c
```

Or

```
$ find . -name '*.c' -exec sed -i your_command {} \;
```

Comment: This works as I expected. Thank you.